# mysql workbench installation failed

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to install the workbench. Server could be installed without problems, but workbench can't be isntalled and there is no hint,what it could be.

I have enough diskspace .

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
```

are installed too.

Any hints from your side ?

```
1: Action 10:46:20: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE 2: {CD8C5EC0-56A3-4F6E-BB22-E230059DF1F2} 
1: Action 10:46:20: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 10:46:20: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 10:46:20: SetWIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_452_OR_LATER_INSTALLED. 
1: Action 10:46:20: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 10:46:20: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 10:46:20: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 10:46:20: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 10:46:20: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 10:46:20: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
1: Action 10:46:20: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: 1: MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE 2: {CD8C5EC0-56A3-4F6E-BB22-E230059DF1F2} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Workbench 6.3.9' failed.
```